# bizarre behavior printf( ) called between 10-13 times per line

Tags: c++, c, printf

I wrote this function that writes a 2D vector to stdio using `printf()`

```
static void printSheet ( const storage::twoDVec& Sheet, char format='g'
                       , char elDelim='\t', char vecDelim='\n') 

    const size_t vecSize = Sheet.vecSize;
    const size_t subVecSize = Sheet.subVecSize;
    char pFormat[3] = {'%', format, elDelim};
    for ( size_t y = 0; y < vecSize; y++ ) {
        for ( size_t x = 0; x < subVecSize; x++ ) {
            printf(pFormat, Sheet.get( y, x ));
        }
    putchar(vecDelim);
    }
}
```

It works great unless `subVecSize` in [10, 13], then the format is not

```
x x x
x x x
x x x
```

For `subVecSize = 10`

```
1
2
...
9
10

1
2
...
9
10
```

(Repeating).  For `11` and `12` the subVectors scroll across diagonally and for `13` the subvectors overwrite themselves. *eg* if `vecSize==1 && subVecSize==3` then I only get one number as an output.

Am I over looking something or do I not understand something fundamental about `printf()`?  Changing `elDelim` to `' '` doesn't change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `pFormat` array is not null terminated. Try this

```
char pFormat[4] = {'%', format, elDelim, '\0'};
```